# ERROR building isaac SDK sample on jetson nano : JetPack43 is not defined in any .rc file

Tags: ubuntu, sdk, nvidia, bazel

I am getting an error when running the isaac sdk sample script (https://docs.nvidia.com/isaac/isaac/doc/tutorials/nano.html) :

```
sudo ./engine/build/deploy.sh --remote_user thoth -p //apps/tutorials/ping:ping-pkg -d 'JetPack43' -h 192.168.0.14 --run
```

The error is :

```
=============================================================
Building Minidump tools
Building //apps/tutorials/ping:ping-pkg for target platform 'JetPack43'
=============================================================
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=125
**ERROR: Config value JetPack43 is not defined in any .rc file**
```

I triple check for any rc files but couldn’t find any. I tryed with `jetpack43`, `jetpack42`, `'jetpack43'`, nothing work.

I followed all the setup steps without any error and can acess ssh without problem and reinstalled bazel manualy.
Running ubuntu 18.04 on PC and jetson nano. Istalled Jetson4.3 and bazel 0.19. bazel is in user/bin and the scrip is in Desktop/isaac/.

In the doc (https://docs.nvidia.com/isaac/isaac/doc/setup.html) there is the following note :

> Bazel requires the file .bazelrc, located in the Isaac SDK package. The Archive Manager application in Ubuntu Linux may fail to extract the hidden file, leading to building errors. If you see errors when building, confirm that .bazelrc is present in the extracted sources.

and in bazel install page (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html) :

> The --user flag installs Bazel to the $HOME/bin directory on your system and sets the .bazelrc path to $HOME/.bazelrc. Use the --help command to see additional installation options.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION :

I finally found the file here is how I did :

(optional)Follow : Using the binary installer https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html

Activate show hidden files with ctr + H (hidden files are .filename)

Go to disk origin

Search .bazelrc

find the one with following code (775bytes located in admin:///home/thoth/.local/share/Trash/files/isaac-sdk-20191213-65ec14db) :

```
build --keep_going --color=yes -c opt --crosstool_top=@toolchain//crosstool:toolchain

build --define=target_platform=x86_64 --strip=always
build --action_env=target_platform="x86_64"
build:x86_64 --define=target_platform=x86_64 --strip=always
build:x86_64 --action_env=target_platform="x86_64"

build:jetpack43 --cpu=arm64-v8a --strip=always
build:jetpack43 --define=target_platform=jetpack43
build:jetpack43 --action_env=target_platform="jetpack43"

test --test_output=errors --keep_going --color=yes -c opt
test --test_tag_filters=-lint

build --python_top=//engine/build:python3
test --python_top=//engine/build:python3
run --python_top=//engine/build:python3

test:lint --build_tests_only
test:lint --test_tag_filters=lint
test:lint --python_top=//engine/build:python27
```

Copy the file

Paste the file into /home/thoth/.bazel/bin/

Run in terminal : sudo ./engine/build/deploy.sh --remote_user thoth -p //apps/tutorials/ping:ping-pkg -d jetpack43 -h 192.168.0.14 --run

Take a coffe because first build take time ;)

Enjoy